# C# WebRequest Forbidden

Tags: c#, webrequest, webresponse

using the URL http://myanimelist.net/malappinfo.php?u=fakemudkipper&status=all&type=anime
And using the code

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://myanimelist.net/malappinfo.php?u=" + username + "&status=all&type=anime");
WebResponse responce = req.GetResponse();
```

This code used to work, but suddenly it no longer works, and returns the error
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
It does load on my web browser.
I have also tried to use

```
req.Credentials= new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

But this did not help

Comment: It works on my computer. You may got blocked by  that site.

Comment: Odd, i just tried it 1 minute ago and it worked, however it does not work now, Is this a server side problem or still local?

Comment: Link works for me.  Probably the server had problems, rebooted and you got caught in the middle. Might just be a bad server.

Comment: Odd that is works 5% of time in c# and 100% of time in a web browser though

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into Webclient

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx

From there you could download the website easier, instead of using webrequests(which already proved bad).

Comment: I have tried downloading it with other methods with things such as WebClient.Downloadhtml /string but with no success i have also tried running this on a different machine and IP but get the same error a % of the time

Comment: In last resort, use a webbrowser(object) to navigate(method) there, and on document complete(event), download(method) the document and do what you with with it.